# Algorithm to rank numeric passcode?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, user-interface, mobile, passwords

I'm studying a (mobile) app where I need to get a user PIN: 
a numeric "passcode" of 6/8 ciphers, input with something like this UI:

[image: passcode mokup]

So, in a registration step, the user configure his one passcode (as it would be a password).

Let say the passcode must have a fixed size (say 8 ciphers: ********)

My question is related to a possible algorithm to verify/check the number that user choose, giving a bad rank in case of repeated ciphers or standard cipher patterns (`12345678`, `00001111`), easily predicible by a malicious crackers...

Any idea for such an algorithm ?

At firs glance the algorithm could discourage (bad rank) a passcod containing repeated ciphers, simething like:

```
00117788
88886611
```

or "usual" ascending/descending patterns as:

```
12345678
98765432
```

Or numeric patterns related to personal, by example in my case, I'm born in 02 September 1963, so it could be a bad idea to have as passcode:

```
02091963
```

Instead, sequence that appear to me as "good" could be by example these one:

```
18745098 
90574808
07629301
```

Collateral question: do you think that a numeric passcode of let say 8 ciphers could be an acceptable solution as "password" to validate a payment transaction ?

BTW, I'm coding in Ruby.

thanks for your patience!

giorgio

Comment: As for your collateral question: I think it depends on the importance of the transaction. In NL the national bank does use 8 ciphers in combination with a random number generator.

Comment: thanks for info. in my case, the passcode could be used to "identify"/"sign" an user a payment transaction in a person-to-person context: a buyer digit his code in a retailer tablet when buying something in the seller shop... see: https://twitter.com/solyarisoftware/status/578261098887036929

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first 2 cases:

Number of repeated consecutive characters in the string:

```
str = "00117788"
str.chars.each_cons(2).select {|a,b| a == b}.count
#=> 4
```

Or as @CarySwoveland pointed out this will have the same result

```
str.size - str.squeeze.size
#=> 4
```

Number of incremented characters

```
str = "12345678"
str.chars.map(&:to_i).each_slice(2).select {|a,b| (a + 1) == b || (a - 1) == b }.count
#=> 4
#note this will also return 4 for "12563478"
# you could also use str.chars.map(&:to_i).each_cons(2).select {|a,b| (a + 1) == b || (a - 1) == b }.count
# This will return 7 for "12345678" and still return 4 for "12563478"
```

You could combine the above 2 as well like

```
str = "00117788"
str.chars.map(&:to_i).each_cons(2).select {|a,b| (a + 1) == b || (a - 1) == b || a == b }.count
#=> 6
```

As for the "personal" issue if you have the birth day then something as simple as this should work:

```
require 'date'
birth_day = Date.new(1963,9,2)
str = "02091963"
str == birth_day.strftime("%d%m%Y")
#=> true
```

Although for the last one I would suggest comparing multiple formats e.g. `%Y%m%d` and `%m%d%Y` etc. you could even do something like

```
str.chars.sort == birth_day.strftime("%d%m%Y").chars.sort
#=> true
```

To make sure they don't just use those numbers in some jumbled format.

Hopefully this would get you started since I don't know what your thresholds are for "good" and "bad" these are just suggestions for checking the values. Although it seems the definition for "good" should just be not "bad". Sort of like a validity check.

If I were to suggest a score of < 4 using methods 1 and 2 (or the combination method) && not an assortment of birth_day numbers would probably be sufficient e.g.

```
def tester(str,birth_date)
  return false if ![6,8].include?(str.size)
  b_day = birth_date.strftime("%Y%m%d").chars.sort
  str.chars.map(&:to_i).each_cons(2).select  do |a,b| 
    (a + 1) == b || 
    (a - 1) == b || 
    a == b 
  end.count < 4 && b_day != str.chars.sort
end
tester("00112233",Date.new(1963,9,2))
#=> false
tester("18745098",Date.new(1963,9,2))
#=> true
```

Seems like it works with your examples

```
arry = ["00117788","88886611","12345678","98765432","02091963","18745098","90574808","07629301"]
Hash[arry.map{|v| [v,tester(v,Date.new(1963,9,2))]}]
#=>=> {"00117788"=>false, "88886611"=>false, 
       "12345678"=>false, "98765432"=>false, 
       "02091963"=>false, "18745098"=>true, 
       "90574808"=>true, "07629301"=>true}
```

Comment: For repeated consecutive characters, consider using [String#squeeze](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-squeeze): `str.size - str.squeeze.size`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you I have added it to my answer along with a combination of part 1 and 2 using `Enumerable#each_cons`.

Comment: thanks engineersmnky! great ruby chunks. You are right: I have been vague on definition of bad/good. A basic ide a with 8 ciphers: good passcode -> rank:8; all digit in sequenze -> rank:0. I have to think more about it :-) My goal in general is just to avoid really "stupid" passcodes. I described the context in a comment above, so the passcode is a "soft" password mode to be placed side by side with a facial ("selfie") recognition in a person to person trade; indeed I'm fully aware about the wekness of a passcode...